# Reference value of constant with KDoc

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-dokka, kdoc

I have a `object` like the following in my project

```
object UrlUtils {

    private const val PARAM = "whatever"

    /**
     * Method that appends the [PARAM] parameter to the url
     */
    fun appendParameter(url: String) {
        // ...
    }

}
```

As you can see a I wanna reference the value of the `PARAM` field in the KDoc comment of the `appendParameter` method however when looking at the comment I don't see the actual value but only the name of the field.

> Method that appends the PARAM parameter to the url

What I want:

> Method that appends the whatever parameter to the url

In Javadoc this works by using `{@value PARAM}` but there seems to be nothing similar in KDoc. Even the automatic code-converter keeps the old Javadoc.

So my question: Am I missing something or is KDoc/Dokka missing this feature?

Answer (score 5):

Currently, `{@value}` tags are not supported by KDoc.

The closest issue requesting this is [#488](https://github.com/Kotlin/dokka/issues/488), so you can up-vote and/or comment on it.

Comment: Looks like that was implemented in 1.4.x but to me it is not the thing that I would like to see and also not the thing that original question asked for. Dokka can now render default value of `fun` parameter if it was assigned a primitive constant. But "unwrapping" it's value in rendered kdoc (`/** MY DOCUMENTATION */`) is sadly not there, as I understood.

Comment: Exactly. The values of constants are documented by default, but you can't reference any such value from an arbitrary KDoc fragment the way you could do in JavaDoc.